# How could hydrogen in a vacuum be removed/extracted?

Tags: science-based, biology, chemistry, biochemistry, vacuum

What reactions or process could remove hydrogen from the vacuum without compromising it, then from there a way that animals could do it, the vacuum is in a rigid space, but hydrogen still seeps through, a way to either stop that or remove the hydrogen from the space would be much appreciated

Comment: Removing - to create a deeper vacuum, or replacing it with other gases is acceptable?

Comment: purer vacuum, not replacing the hydrogen with something else, apart from nothingness

Answer (score 7):

There are substances called [getters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getter) which are used to absorb volatile elements in sealed vacuum chambers, which, for obvious reasons, cannot be pumped down more than once. For example they were used in CRTs.

> A getter is a deposit of reactive material that is placed inside a vacuum system, for the purpose of completing and maintaining the vacuum. When gas molecules strike the getter material, they combine with it chemically or by absorption. Thus the getter removes small amounts of gas from the evacuated space. The getter is usually a coating applied to a surface within the evacuated chamber. [...] hydrogen is usually handled by adsorption rather than reaction.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: And home-made vacuum tubes.